# XSLT: Referencing a node set beyond the current xsl:for-each using position()

Tags: xslt, xpath

Compare these two XML extracts:

(1)

```
<Parents>
   <Parent>
      <ChildOne>a</ChildOne>
      <ChildTwo>b</ChildTwo>
      <ChildThree>c</ChildThree>
   </Parent>
   <Parent>
      <ChildOne>x</ChildOne>
      <ChildTwo>y</ChildTwo>
      <ChildThree>z1</ChildThree>
   </Parent>
   <Parent>
      <ChildOne>x</ChildOne>
      <ChildTwo>y</ChildTwo>
      <ChildThree>z2</ChildThree>
   </Parent>
</Parents>
```

(2)

```
<Parents>
   <Parent>
      <ChildOne>x</ChildOne>
      <ChildTwo>y</ChildTwo>
      <ChildThree>z1</ChildThree>
   </Parent>
   <Parent>
      <ChildOne>x</ChildOne>
      <ChildTwo>y</ChildTwo>
      <ChildThree>z2</ChildThree>
   </Parent>
</Parents>
```

Say I want to find the value of /ChildThree for all instances of /Parent where /ChildOne has the value "x" and /ChildTwo has the value "y", but add some kind of extra marker if the first such instance is also the first of ALL instances of /Parent

So, for (1) above, I want this output:

z1 z2

And for (2) above, I want this output:

z1 This is the first Parent. z2

To achieve this, if I use an xsl:for-each as follows:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Parent[ChildOne='x'][ChildTwo='y']">
   <xsl:if test="position()&gt;=2">
      <xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="ChildThree"/>
   <xsl:if test="ExpressionHere">
      <xsl:text>&#x20;This&#x20;is&#x20;the&#x20;first&#x20;Parent.</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

...what XPath expression do I need where it says, "ExpressionHere"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the **preceding-sibling** axis here, to test if your current **Parent** element has any siblings that precede it.

```
<xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::Parent)">
   <xsl:text>This is the first Parent.</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

Alternatively, if you need really want to find the position of the **Parent** element, regardless of the ChildOne and ChildTwo criteria, you could use the **xsl:number** command, although you would need to put this in a variable to reference it

```
<xsl:variable name="position">
   <xsl:number />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:if test="$position = 1">
   <xsl:text>This is the first Parent.</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thank you - that's useful information. So, basically, the position() function references context-specific position; and the default value of xsl:number references absolute position in the source. preceding-sibling would be ideal in the case of my example, but preceding-sibling and following-sibling are only useful if I'm testing whether a node is first or last - not in other scenarios where I might want to find the position.